# FTP status check using a variable - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ftp

I am doing an ftp and I want to check the status. I don't want to use '$?' as mostly it returns 0 (Success) for ftp even though internally ftp didn't go through.

I know I can check the log file and do a grep from there for "Transfer complete" (221 status). That works fine but I don't want to do it as I have many different reports doing ftp. So creating multiple log files for all of them is what I want to avoid.

Can I get the logged information in a local script variable and process it inside the script itself?
Something similar to these (I've tried both but neither worked):

- [Grab FTP output in BASH SCRIPT](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/grab-ftp-output-in-bash-script-399836/)
- [FTP status check whether successful or not](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/221797-ftp-status-check-whether-successful-not.html)

Below is something similar to what I am trying to do:

```
ftp -inv ${HOST} > log_file.log  <<! 
user ${USER} ${PASS}
bin
cd "${TARGET}"
put ${FEEDFILE}
bye
!
```

Any suggestions on how can I get the entire ftp output in a script variable and then check it within the script?

Comment: You say "didn't work"; you don't explain in what way they didn't work.  Was the output not written to your log file?  Was the output not written at all?  Was it written to standard error instead of standard output?

Comment: If I create a variable and equate it to the ftp command. Nothing is being returned. Variable is still empty. Something like this  `STATUS=`ftp -n $HOST > log_file.log <<!  USER $USER
PASS $PASSWD
cd /user/sba-appl/test
bye
EOF'`  here STATUS is empty.  I want my variable to get what is being logged in the log file.    Sorry for inappropriate code structure.

Answer (score 1):

To capture stdout to a variable you can use bash's [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), so either `` OUTPUT=`cmd` `` or `OUTPUT=$(cmd)`.

Here's an example how to capture the output from `ftp` in your case:

```bash
CMDS="user ${USER} ${PASS}
bin
cd \"${TARGET}\"
put \"${FEEDFILE}\"
bye"

OUTPUT=$(echo "${CMDS}" | ftp -inv ${HOST})
```